# find how many quarters a person has using modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to solve this problem using modular arithmetic?

> Wendy noticed when she stacked her quarters in piles of $5$ she had $3$ left over, and when she stacked them in piles of $7$ she had $5$ left over. If she has less than then dollars worth of quarters, how many quarters does she have?

$$$$

Based on the information I have $$a=3 \pmod 5$$ $$a=5 \pmod 7$$ in which $a$ is the total quarter. Then what do I do?

Comment: Did you mean less than *ten* dollars worth of quarters?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$a\equiv3\pmod5\equiv-2$$

$$a\equiv5\pmod7\equiv-2$$

Clearly, $a+2$ needs to be divisible by $5,7$  hence by their LCM

Had the remainders not been same, we needed to use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)

Comment: In a+2, is it from 5-3, or 7-5?

Comment: @FSK, In $\pmod5,$  its $3-5$  and $...$

Comment: Since $a \equiv -2 \mod 5$, add $2$ to both sides of the equation to get $a +2\equiv 0 \mod 5$, same for $a \equiv -2 \mod 7$. That gives you $a+2 \equiv 0 \mod 5$ and $a+2 \equiv 0 \mod 7$, hence $a+2$ must be divisible by both $5$ and $7$ because the remainder in $\mod 5$ and $\mod 7$ is $0$.